# Why does my FlatList component reset from zero each time and render all items at once?

Tags: php, reactjs, sockets, io, message

`  // Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display
// Logic for game over or final score display

````
`import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
            // Logic for game over or final score display

const Game = () => {
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
    const [time, setTime] = useState(30);
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        let timer;
        if (isActive && time > 0) {
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                setTime(time - 1);
            }, 1000);
        } else {    // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display

            setIsActive(false);
            // Logic for game over or final score display
        }

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, [isActive, time]);

    const handleStart = () => {
        setIsActive(true);
    };

    const handleIncrement = () => {
        setScore(score + 1);
    };
            // Logic for game over or final score display

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.timer}>{`Time: ${time}`}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.score}>{`Score: ${score}`}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleStart}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{isActive ? 'Running' : 'Start'}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleIncrement}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Increment Score</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};             // Logic for game over or final score display

  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display
  // Logic for game over or final score display

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    timer: {
        fontSize: 24,
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    score: {
        fontSize: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    button: {
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#3498db',
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 18,
    },
});
     
export default Game;
```   `
````